# OpenTelemetry Collector With Kafka Exporter - customising the payload

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am using `OpenTelemetry` collector to collect logs from Springboot (3) app.

Want to add Exporter: Kafka  - to store the logs in Kafka for some future processing.

otel-collector-config.yaml

```
extensions:
  health_check:

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:

processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_size: 10000
    timeout: 5s

exporters:
  kafka:
    brokers:
      - localhost: 9092
    protocol_version: 2.0.0
  logging:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging,kafka]

  extensions: [health_check]
```

I report logs from my app, as usual:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(My.class);
log.info("FOO id {} tag {} sn{} /*more tags */", id, tag,sn);
```

Is it possible to format the payload that will be stored in Kafka? Is it possible to set key for the Kafka message?